# Problem using wp_remote_post to parse JSON response from external API

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, plugins

I am using [wp_remote_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) to post products to a third party site. First I get these products via API from a site called Mercado Libre. But when I carry out the mass publication, the products are published without a name, without a price, and without respecting the parameters provided. They only have the name "Product".

[image: Product published without data]

```
function publish_products_in_woocommerce()
{

    $respuesta = wp_remote_get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=Motorola%20G6', array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer APP_USR-2778915669536100-052221-0f3a39361bdcea9bc3de0df8ab619f66-370993848'
        )
    ));
    $respuesta = json_decode($respuesta['body'], true);
    print_r($respuesta);
    foreach ($respuesta['results'] as $value) {
        $product_data = array(
            'name' => $value['title'],
            'status' => 'draft',
            'type' => 'simple',
            'regular_price' => $value['price'],
            'description' => $value['title'],
            'short_description' => $value['title'],
            'categories' => [
                [
                    'id' => $value['category_id'],
                ]
            ],
            'images' => [
                [
                    'src' => $value['thumbnail']
                ]
            ]

        );

        $woocommerce_api_ck = 'ck_b2a0f58d07590e8283302eca04fbc1b66a9ff653';
        $woocommerce_api_cs = 'cs_b4d91662590be47416f663fc9f0d1c49f600e394';

        $url = 'http://nuevo.labisbal.com.ar/wp-json/wc/v3/products';

        wp_remote_post('http://nuevo.labisbal.com.ar/wp-json/wc/v3/products', array(
            'headers' => array(

                'Authorization ' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($woocommerce_api_ck . ':' . $woocommerce_api_cs),
            ),

            'body' =>  $ProductToWooCommerce = json_encode($product_data),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'timeout' => 145,
            'blocking' => false,
            'sslverify' => false,
            'stream' => true,
            'data_format' => 'json'




        ));
        print_r($ProductToWooCommerce);
        if (wp_remote_retrieve_response_message($respuesta) === 'Created') {
            echo 'The product  has been created';
        }
    }
}
publish_products_in_woocommerce();

?>
```

It's strange because when I display the json already converted (using json_encode) the data is displayed correctly... (using print_r)

[image: Screenshot of JSON output]

Comment: Is that your API key on the question?

Comment: Its a fake key!

Answer (score 1):

I take a look at this and the issue is on how you sent the data to the API, when you use wp_remote_post you need to send the body as an array, and the method handles that information for you, so you don't need to convert it to JSON.

Below is a small test plugin that saves products using the WC REST API, the plugin adds a new endpoint to your site to trigger the scrapper `https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wpapi/v1/fetch`, I hope that helps.

Note: Please double check the code, is not fully tested.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       A WC API test
 * Plugin URI:        https://enriquechavez.co
 * Description:       Just a test.
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP:      7.4
 * Author:            Enrique Chavez
 * Author URI:        https://enriquechavez.co/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Update URI:        https://example.com/my-plugin/
 * Text Domain:       my-basics-plugin
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wpapi/v1', 'fetch', [
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'fetch_ml_products',
        'permissions_callback' => '__return_true',
    ]);
});

function fetch_ml_products(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    $ml_api = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLM/search?q=Motorola%20G6&limit=5';
    $wc_ck = 'ck_1f2e32852403a1701c1adxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $wc_cs = 'cs_6fd5feedd2a25b73eebc9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $request = wp_safe_remote_get($ml_api);

    if (is_wp_error($request)) {
        return $request;
    }

    $response = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($request));
    $new_products = [];

    foreach ($response->results as $product) {
        $wc_api_url = 'https://wp.test/wp-json/wc/v3/products/';

        $request_data = [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($wc_ck . ':' . $wc_cs),
            ],
            'body' => [
                'name' => $product->title,
                'status' => 'draft',
                'regular_price' => $product->price,
            ],
            'sslverify' => false,
        ];

        $request = wp_remote_post($wc_api_url, $request_data);

        if (is_wp_error($request)) {
            // TODO: validate the error.
            print_r($request);
            die('Something is wrong');
        }

        $new_products[] = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($request));
    }

    return $new_products;
}
```

Comment: Oh this is great! Thank you very much for your information. It is really very valuable to me. I am going to try your plugin and I am sure that with your information this will work out.

Thanks a lot!!!